# How to extract hashed password from the response

Tags: jmeter

I am designing a jmeter script in which the following happens:

1. User enters username and password and then client/browser generates a 6 digit random number.
2. Server also generates a random number.
3. These 2 random numbers are used along with the password supplied by the user and then sha256 hashing technique is used to generate a password and that is sent as a request parameter to the server.
4. The issue is how do I extract the hashed password from the response so that it can be sent along with the request.

Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: Do you want to reverse the hashing function and retrieve the original password?

Comment: Not really. The original password, along with the client random number and server random number are used to generate the hashed password, which is sent as a request parameter to the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can generate a 6-digit random number in JMeter with [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random)
2. You can extract server-generated 6-digit random number using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
3. You can generate an SHA-256 hash of the password + 2 random numbers using [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest)

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I added the following in bean shell post processor:

1) This is used to generate a 6 digit client random number

${__Random(000000,999999, clientNumber)};

2) Then I used the digest function to generate the hashed password and stored it in hashedPwd. I am using debug sampler to print the variables on console but don't know why I am unable to print it

${__digest(SHA-256,${clientNumber},${serverNumber},hashedPwd)};